# How can I get the value of a Angular Material element in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this HTML little code, one is a common HTML button and the other is an Angular Material Icon button.

```
<button mat-button #matbutton value="007">mat-button</button>

<button #button value="342">button</button>
```

I'm trying to get the value of both them in the .ts file as follows:

```
  @ViewChild('matinput', { static: true }) matinput: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('button', { static: true }) button: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.button.nativeElement.value);  
    console.log(this.matinput.nativeElement.value);
  }
```

I only get the value of the normal HTML button, but I can't get the value of the angular material button... How can achieve this? I tried removing "nativeElement" but didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `mat-button` directive, so if you want to get the elementRef of this button (MatButton) you need to explicitly declare `read: ElementRef` on the properties of `ViewChild`.

Default `ViewChild` is reading the element as the directive.

```
@ViewChild('matButton', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) matButton: ElementRef;
```

Resources about ViewChild:

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/

Comment: Thank you, Master!, May you explain to me why does this work? I tried to google but didn't find about the read: ElementRef. ¿Do I have to use it every time I use an HTML element using any kind of directive?

Comment: You're welcome! You can check the angular documentation about ViewChild: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild. You need to use read:  ElementRef when you're trying to read the ElementRef of a component or directive.